# CSS text position in the right of a column next to a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a progress bar filled with color and on the right side, I would like to display the percentage as a text.

Take into account that the width of the color changes based on the percentage.

The problem is in the right text. It is not in the right on the gray area instead it is in the right of the blue area.

What I have so far

[image]

What I want

[image]

```css
.fill {
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #14cbeb;
}

#soft-tool {
  color: white;
  background: #0e8aa0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="row bg-light text-white">
    <div id="soft-tool" class="col-sm-2 text-center">
      <h5>CSS</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 px-0">
      <div class="fill">
        <div class="text-right">80%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using bootstrap. I tried to use columns but it doesn't help because of the percentages, these are going to change based on the category.

```html
<div class="row bg-light text-white">
    <div id="soft-tool" class="col-sm-2 text-center">
      <h5>CSS</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 px-0">
      <div class="fill">
        <div class="text-right">80%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.fill {
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #14cbeb;
}

#soft-tool {
  color: white;
  background: #0e8aa0;
}
```

The bar should contain 3 sections,

1. Name
2. Color based on the percentage
3. Percentage in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clearfix](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/) in combination with [`float-left` and `float:right`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/):

```
  <div class="text-white clearfix fill">
    <div id="soft-tool" class="float-left"><h5>CSS</h5></div>
    <div id="percent" class="float-right bg-light text-right">80%</div>
  </div>
```

You can then easily set the width of the progress bar by changing the width of `#percent` in the CSS (eg. for 80% progress, set the width of `#percent` to 20%).

Full demo:

```css
.fill {
  height: 35px;
  background: #14cbeb;
}

#soft-tool {
  color: white;
  background: #0e8aa0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}

#percent {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div class="text-white clearfix fill">
    <div id="soft-tool" class="float-left"><h5>CSS</h5></div>
    <div id="percent" class="float-right bg-light text-right">80%</div>
  </div>
  
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You nailed it! I've missed clearfix at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following uses bootstrap classes and components.

```
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
  <span>Name</span>
  <div class="progress w-100">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <span>20%</span>
</div>
```

Style accordingly.

If for whatever reason, you want to use your own custom progress bar, in between the two spans, nest it between a div with a class of w-100 (or width: 100%).

```
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
  <span>Name</span>
  <div class="w-100">
    Custom Progress bar
  </div>
  <span>20%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but @glhr just nailed it. Thanks anyways.